# Error When adding Object to NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am getting errors when trying to add items to a NSMutableArray which is encapsulated within an object.

Code follows:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface TestObject : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *myArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myArray;


@end

#import "TestObject.h"


@implementation TestObject

@synthesize myArray;

- (id) init {
    if(self= [super init]){
        // Initialise the Mutable Array
        myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [myArray release];
}
@end
```

Calling:

```
TestObject *testObject = [[TestObject alloc] init];
    NSString *someString = @"blah blah blah";
    NSLog(@"%@", someString);
    [testObject.myArray addObject:someString];
    NSLog(@"Test Object Array Count: %@", [testObject.myArray count]);
    [testObject release];
```

Can anyone tell me why this throws an error when calling count?

I have also tried the copy the Mutable Array to a local variable and get the same result when calling count on the local variable.

Comment: Fixed my own issue.
NSLog(@"Test Object Array Count: %d", [testObject.myArray count]);

Comment: Not trying to answer your question but I strongly suggest moving that [myArray release] call in your -dealloc to before you do the super call.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, little oversight on my part. I typed that code out by hand in Safari as I do not have xcode on this machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning warning warning!!!**

`[super dealloc]` is the *last* thing you should do in your `-dealloc` method, *not* the first!

Answer (score 0):

It's a good thing it just showed a warning, when I have done the same it has crashed.

The reason is that %@ is an object placeholder. But the count method returns NSInteger which is a primitive datatype and the placeholder for it is %d, as you have correctly noted in the comment.